# Content going beneath fixed header of unknown variable height

Tags: html, css, fixed

I have a `<header>` that is `position: fixed;` to the top of the display.

The natural consequence of this is that `<main>` ends up going underneath the fairly sizeable `<header>`.

I've faced this problem before and have solved it with a simple `margin-top` assignment on `<main>`. Here the issue is a little different though.

The height of the `<header>` is variable and unknown. It has top and bottom padding of 5px and a bottom margin of 5px. It has no explicitly set height of its own; it is decided by the content within.

The largest element in the `<header>` is an image that is assigned its height as `20vh`. There is also an `<h1>` and `<h3>`, again sized using `<vh>` units. I know of no way that allows me to offset `<main>` so it is always below this dynamically-sized, responsive `<header>`.

I've been browsing SO but have found no single accepted solution to solve this. Many ideas rest solely on catching window resizes with JavaScript, getting the computed height of the header and assigning the top of main to match. I fear this approach will decrease performance and also introduce annoying page jumps/leaps etc. as JS catches up with the scrolling.

How this is kind of problem usually tackled in responsive design? Ideally, I'm looking for a pure CSS solution to this problem, or some kind of workaround for `position: fixed;'. Failing that, an elegant and versatile JS solution that doesn't hinder performance. This issue is causing me problems, because none of my usual attempts to resolve absolute/fixed positioning headaches are able to help.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

-Ilmiont

Comment: How will javascript hinder your performance? You dont need JQuery, it can be done with a couple lines of simple javacsript.

Comment: And how about you create an example.

Answer (score 1):

I would check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6763095/creating-a-variable-height-fixed-header-in-css-with-scrollable-content#6763409). They mention pushing the content down with a second header or using javascript.

My guess is javascript would be a cleaner approach so you don't have extra content and unnecessary requests being made to the server.